# How can I create magento 2 url rewrites?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, magento2

I want to *Create Url Rewrites in Magento 2* to make easily for customers. Can you help me to do it?

Comment: Magento has in admin section URL rewrites option.You want URL rewrite for products or for other URLs as well.

Answer (score -1):

Take it easy with this tutorial, I think it is all things you get it. 
View more at >>>
http://www.venustheme.com/magento-2-url-rewrites/

Admin >>> Marketing >>> URL Rewrites
In the feature of URL Rewrites, you can choose ” your product” and “Edit” it.

Then "Save”.

Good luck!